# How can I connect to Spring WebSocket server from IOS client?

Tags: swift, spring, websocket

We are developing a Chat application using Spring Boot WebSocket. 
Users can login to the chat applicaton, hosted in Tomcat and send messages to other online users.
We are unable to connect from another iOS client to the same chat application.

Below is our code implementation in server and client

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
// Server side implementation
///////////////////////////////////////////

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/message");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/tracking").withSockJS();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(WebsocketConfiguration.class);

    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "IP_ADDRESS";

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/message");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        log.debug("registering StompEndpoints");
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket/tracker")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
                    // custom authentication 
                }).withSockJS()
                .setInterceptors(httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor httpSessionHandshakeInterceptor() {
        return new HandshakeInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
                    ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                    Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
                if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                    ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
                    attributes.put(IP_ADDRESS,
                            servletRequest.getRemoteAddress());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
                    ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                    Exception exception) {

            }
        };
    }
}



    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // Web Client side socket creation code 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    var stompClient = null;
    function connect() {

     if (stompClient != null) {
      stompClient.disconnect();
     }

     var socket = new SockJS(contextPath + '/tracking');
     stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
     stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      stompClient.subscribe('/message/send/individual/' + loginUserUk,
        function(response) {
         var messageBody1 = JSON.parse(response.body);
         //process with the response

        });
     });
    }





    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // IOS Client side code 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////       
   let host = "xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tracking"
   let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "wss://\(host)/")!, protocols:[])
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()

   func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
        if let e = error as? WSError {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.message)")
        } else if let e = error {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("websocket disconnected")
        }
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
        print("Received data: \(data.count)")
    }
```

When we try to connect from iOS (provided in the above code snippet), we are getting the following error : TCP Conn 0x109de3d50 SSLHandshake failed (-9847) websocket is disconnected: The operation couldn’t be completed.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this with "swift", but the code you've posted (client-side) is JavaScript. Also, you've given no information about any error messages received when you try to connect to the server. We need something other than just "unable to connect" if we're to help you.

Comment: When we try to connect from iOS (provided in the above code snippet), we are getting the following error : 
TCP Conn 0x109de3d50 SSLHandshake failed (-9847)

websocket is disconnected: The operation couldn’t be completed.

Comment: Are you sure the server has a valid SSL cert? If you have the source code for the app, try setting "App Transport Security > Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES temporarily, and see if that solves the issue. If it does, then your server has an invalid or self-signed cert.

Comment: Thank you. We have setup the free SSL cert from letsencrypt. We have also tried setting  "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES permanantly in the IOS App code.

Comment: The error you are seeing is definitely an SSL, so check that your server is configured correctly. Allow Arbitrary Loads will allow any SSL cert, so if this didn't work, then it's almost certainly a server issue. Check that the server has actually had the cert applied properly (restart may be needed). Bad firewall/router config on your network could also cause SSL issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the URL which you are using from iOS client. The Websocket runs on top of HTTP where client and server communicate over TCP once the HTTP connection is established.

When you connect a client from a browser, all you are doing is, initiating the  HTTP request. Once the server acknowledge the request, it sets up a TCP connection with client browser. This is where you use SockJS(contextPath + '/tracking'); to send the message over TCP layer.

In order to connect your iOS client with same server, all you have to do is, send the HTTP request and not the one with "wss:". As long as you send the request with correct endpoint from iOS client, you should be good.

```
 let host = "xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tracking"
       let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "http://\(host)/")!, protocols:[])
            socket.delegate = self
            socket.connect()
```